# Coordinate System problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have 3 shp layers, representing the coastline of South Africa, the harbour area and the study area.
I first loaded the coastline and the harbour area, and put them into the WGS 84 - UTM 35S (EPSG 32735). The problem comes with the third layer. Although it has a .prj file, QGIS asks to select the SCR. Whatever I select, the layer either do not appear on the scream, or does, but kilometers away from the place it should be.
I tried to export or save the file and the project in different SCR, but in vain... It seems that the coordinates are different, but I cannot manage to change them: for the first two layers, the coordinates look like 27.85, -32.56 and for the third one, it looks like 127627, -3864621 (but the project SCR is the same - EPSG 32735).

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "put them into CRS". Also add an image showing the shift/difference.

Comment: 27.85, -32.56 are not valid WGS 84 - UTM 35S (EPSG 32735) coordinate,your step  "put them into the WGS 84 - UTM 35S (EPSG 32735)" is probably the cause of the problem

Comment: Erik, by "put them into CSR" I meant that I changed from WGS 84 EPSG 4326

Comment: because you probably changed the CRS of your layer instead of reprojecting it, so your project is in 32735 but your layer are not reprojected on the fly and are displayed at 27.85m, -32.56m while the should be reprojected from 27.85°, -32.56°

Comment: what do you mean by 'reprojecting it'?

Comment: I mean converting the coordinate from one CRS to an other, it could be done by exporting your original layer and setting the choosen destination CRS in the export dialog or by using the reprojection tool from the processing toolbox (both way create a new layer with updated coordinate)

Comment: No, that's what I did... I created a new file, saved in the right CRS...

Comment: So your layer may have a wrong projection from the start...

Comment: Okay, that's what I feared... S*** But thanks for the help anyway =)